# Как создать новый язык RU в магазине sylius?

Tags: symfony, symfony3, sylius

Развернул магазин на sylius, в админке настроил русский язык везде, добавил страны, каналы, языки, все что только можно.
Добавил новый локализационный файл messages.ru.yml
Указал в parameters локаль ru (пробовал ru_RU и т.п), и не взлетает сайт...
Все время выдает

```
   An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Channel could not be found! Tip: You can use the Web Debug Toolbar to switch between channels in development.")
```

Ия уже все исходники перерыл не пойму как завести...

Answer (score 0):

**Нашел решение**

> If you use the default theme, then the language select box will automatically appear in the top-left corner of your storefront as soon as you will have more than 1 locale available.
> So, in the admin panel, create the locales you need in the Configuration -> Locales page and add them to the channel you need in the Configuration -> Channels page.

По сути зайти и создать канал, но указывать код ru и округ ru, и тогда заведется, не забыть очистить кеш.